# Not able to edit text in Bash window

Tags: git-bash, ubuntu-server

I am trying to deploy OpenEdx instance on MS azure. For which I am following some instructions. I have created Virtual Machine on Azure. It is Ubuntu Linux VM. I have accessed VM through Git Bash window and I am stuck at below point in post installation process.

The instruction is like:

```
Edit edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/false
```

to

```
edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/bash
```

I have changed the line

```
edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/false
```

to

```
edxapp:x:1003:1006::/edx/app/edxapp:/bin/bash.
```

But, it is not getting edited. How to edit that line? Also,if possible please provide me the script to follow the overall installation, if someone has done OpenEdx installation earlier.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay Sorry for that.Will keep in mind.